# Regular expression to delete lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm working with some fonts and quite often I need to remove some stuff but doing by hand, oops, meaning doing manually, takes an eternity :(

The code looks like this

```
SplineSet
81 830 m 2xd4
664 830 l 2
725 830 742 813 742 766 c 2
...more numbers
Named: "BOX"
```

It should look like this:

```
SplineSet
```

So simply I need to remove a line name "BOX" from glyphs and all numbers and lines associated to this "BOX".

So how can I remove those nasty lines with a regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

**Find what:** `^(\d.*\R)+Named: "BOX"\s*`
**Replace with:** (empty)
**◉  Regular expression**      
**☐  . matches newline**

It will find those lines preceding the `Named: "BOX"` line that start with a digit. That group of lines is removed.